# Load Pivotitems incrementally. Mimic month view in wp8 Calendar

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I want to build a monthview like the native wp8 calendar has.
But I am stuck with the incrementally loading of more Pivotitems when reaching the the end of the initial loaded Pivotitems.

I am kind of confused, how this could be achieved.

Here is my xaml so far:

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="MonthViewPivot" ItemsSource="{Binding Months}" Margin="0"        Loaded="Pivot_Loaded"  SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
       <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Padding="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform TranslateX="0" TranslateY="24"/>
                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>

                    </TextBlock>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="MonthViewGrid" Height="480" Loaded="MonthViewGrid_Loaded" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-10,70">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-30" >
                        <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Mo</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Di</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Mi</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Do</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Fr</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Sa</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">So</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Comment: I am not to sure that this would be your best approach to be honest. As a year is cyclindrical and will always have 12 months, I would suspect that the 'easiest' approach would be to have 12 pivotitems. Set the initial pivot item based on the current date, and update the calendar view and year based on the number of swipes to the left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my solution so far.
I still need to increase the count of PivotItems, but 12 seems to high for a fast UX. I think 5 will do.

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Pocal.MonthViewUserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid x:Name="MonthViewGrid" Margin="0,60,0,0">     
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-30" >
            <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Mon</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Tue</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Wed</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Thu</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Fri</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Sat</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Width="68.5" Padding="6,0" Foreground="Gray">Sun</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

UserControl Code Behind:

```
public partial class MonthViewUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MonthViewUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void loadGridSetup(DateTime dt)
    {
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.Text = dt.ToShortDateString();
        txt.Tap += dayTap;
        (MonthViewGrid as Grid).Children.Add(txt);

    }

    void dayTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
        MonthView.CurrentPage.navigateBackToDay(dt);

    }

}
```

MonthView XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Pocal.MonthView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pocal"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="24,24" FontWeight="SemiBold">2014</TextBlock>
    <phone:Pivot x:Name="MonthsPivot" Margin="0,36,0,0" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

MonthView COde Behind:

```
public partial class MonthView : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public static  MonthView CurrentPage;
    PivotItem pivotItem;
    MonthViewUserControl monthViewUserControl;

    public MonthView()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        CurrentPage = this;
        addFirstThreePivots();

    }



    private void addFirstThreePivots()
    {

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
        DateTime dt2 = dt.AddMonths(1);
        DateTime dt3 = dt.AddMonths(-1);


        addPivotItem(dt);

        addPivotItem(dt2);

        addPivotItem(dt3);


    }

    private void addPivotItem(DateTime dt)
    {
        monthViewUserControl = new MonthViewUserControl();
        monthViewUserControl.loadGridSetup(dt);

        pivotItem = new PivotItem();
        pivotItem.Content = monthViewUserControl;
        pivotItem.DataContext = dt;
        pivotItem.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pivotItem.Header = dt.ToString("MMMM");

        MonthsPivot.Items.Add(pivotItem);
    }


    private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        DependencyObject selectedPivotItem = ((Pivot)sender).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex);
        if (selectedPivotItem == null)
            return;


        DateTime removedDateTime =  (DateTime)(e.RemovedItems[0] as PivotItem).DataContext;
        DateTime addedDateTime =  (DateTime)(e.AddedItems[0] as PivotItem).DataContext;
        if (removedDateTime < addedDateTime)
        {
            forwardPan(addedDateTime);
        }
        else
            backwardPan(addedDateTime);

    }

    private void forwardPan(DateTime addedDateTime)
    {
        PivotItem nextPivotItem = (PivotItem)getNextPivotItem();
        DateTime newDateTime = addedDateTime.AddMonths(1);

        MonthViewUserControl monthViewItem = new MonthViewUserControl();
        monthViewItem.loadGridSetup(newDateTime);
        nextPivotItem.DataContext = newDateTime;
        nextPivotItem.Content = monthViewItem;
        nextPivotItem.Header = newDateTime.ToString("MMMM");
    }

    private DependencyObject getNextPivotItem()
    {
        int index = ((Pivot)MonthsPivot).SelectedIndex;
        int nextIndex;
        if (index == 2)
        {
            nextIndex = 0;
        }
        else
            nextIndex = index + 1;

        DependencyObject nextPivotItem = ((Pivot)MonthsPivot).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(nextIndex);
        return nextPivotItem;
    }



    private void backwardPan(DateTime addedDateTime)
    {

        PivotItem previousPivotItem = (PivotItem)getPreviousPivotItem();
        DateTime newDateTime = addedDateTime.AddMonths(-1);

        MonthViewUserControl monthViewItem = new MonthViewUserControl();
        monthViewItem.loadGridSetup(newDateTime);
        previousPivotItem.DataContext = newDateTime;
        previousPivotItem.Content = monthViewItem;
        previousPivotItem.Header = newDateTime.ToString("MMMM");
    }

    private DependencyObject getPreviousPivotItem()
    {
        int index = ((Pivot)MonthsPivot).SelectedIndex;
        int previousIndex;
        if (index == 0)
        {
            previousIndex = 2;
        }
        else
            previousIndex = index - 1;

        DependencyObject previousPivotItem = ((Pivot)MonthsPivot).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(previousIndex);
        return previousPivotItem;
    }


    public void navigateBackToDay(DateTime dt)
    {
        App.ViewModel.GoToDate(dt);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Mainpage.xaml?GoToDate=", UriKind.Relative), dt);
    }


}
```